# I want to optimize my sql query. Becasuse long response time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

First İ use wherehas but then I decided use this way. This way result better than wherehas but It isn't satisfy me. Query response time is a 873ms. So I have 400k+ data in the table.

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `orders` 
where (`pickup_address_id` in (
    select `id` 
    from `addresses` 
    where `region_id` = 12) 
 or `delivery_address_id` in (
    select `id` 
    from `addresses` 
    where `region_id` = 12)
) and `orders`.`status` = 2
```

Comment: Do you have Index expressions for `addresses.region_id` and `orders.status`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Sure, I add index for region id in addresses table and status in oders table

Comment: Would it be OK to count twice if both the pickup and delivery were in region 12?

Comment: What percentage of orders are in region 12?  If it is a pretty low percentage, turning the query inside-out might speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(distinct o.`id`) as aggregate 
from `orders` o
inner join `addresses` a ON a.`id` IN (o.`pickup_address_id`, o.`delivery_address_id`)
    AND a.`region_id` = 12
where o.`status` = 2
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT count(distinct id) as aggregate
FROM (
    select o.`id`
    from `orders` o
    inner join `addresses` a ON a.`id` = o.`pickup_address_id`
        AND a.`region_id` = 12
    where o.`status` = 2

    UNION

    select o.`id` 
    from `orders` o
    inner join `addresses` a ON a.`id` = o.`delivery_address_id`
        AND a.`region_id` = 12
    where o.`status` = 2
) t
```

But I don't know you'll improve much to look through 400K rows in less than a second.

Comment: Thanks for commented and explainig. But I executed this query response time great than my query (((

Comment: (The second query does "distinct" twice, once in COUNT, once in UNION; toss one of them.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to eliminate multiple (twice, to be more precise) same subquery evaluation using a `Common Table Expression`

```
WITH CTE(id) AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM addresses
    WHERE region_id = 12
)
```

This CTE would be evaluated once.

Second, get row count from `orders` table joined with `cte` on existence of `pickup_address_id` and `delivery_address_id` in `cte`.

```
WITH CTE(id) AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM addresses
    WHERE region_id = 12
)
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM orders
CROSS JOIN CTE ON CTE.id = orders.delivery_address_id
               OR CTE.id = orders.pickup_address_id
```

Finally, add filter by `status = 2` and query would be like

```
WITH CTE(id) AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM addresses
    WHERE region_id = 12
)
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM orders
CROSS JOIN CTE ON CTE.id = orders.delivery_address_id
               OR CTE.id = orders.pickup_address_id
WHERE orders.status = 2
```

Also you should have the following indexes:

`addresses` table:

```
INDEX (region_id)
```

`orders` table:

```
INDEX (pickup_address_id),
INDEX (delivery_address_id),
INDEX (status)
```

Give it a try.

With empty tables I've got this

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table addresses (
  id int primary key,
  region_id int not null,
  index(region_id)
  );
  
create table orders (
  id int primary key,
  pickup_address_id int,
  delivery_address_id int,
  status int not null,
  index (pickup_address_id),
  index (delivery_address_id),
  index(status),
  foreign key (pickup_address_id) references addresses(id),
  foreign key (delivery_address_id) references addresses(id)
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
explain with cte(id) as (
  select id from addresses where region_id = 12)
select count(*) from orders 
cross join cte on cte.id = orders.delivery_address_id
               or cte.id = orders.pickup_address_id
where status = 2;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | orders |  | ref | pickup_address_id,delivery_address_id,status | status | 4 | const | 1 | 100 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | addresses |  | ref | PRIMARY,region_id | region_id | 4 | const | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

---